# How to fix "Property 'value' doesnt exist on type CheckBoxData[ ]"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am recently trying to convert a React app from JS to TS. On doing so I came up with this problem. And idea on how to fix this. Is my conversion  to ts method wrong??

I added interfaces to my JS code and hoping that would be it but I couldnt get past this problem

```
export default React.memo<CheckBoxProps>(
  ({
**line23->**  data: { value, editable = true, error, label, required = false, name },
    focused,
    userColor,
    listeners
  }) => {
    const hasError = !!error;
    return (
      <CheckboxWrapper focused={focused} userColor={userColor}>
        <Checkbox
          name={name}
          isChecked={value}
          isInvalid={hasError}
          // isDisabled={!editable}
          isRequired={required}
          label={label}
          {...listeners}
        />
        {error && <Error>{error}</Error>}
      </CheckboxWrapper>
    );
  }
);

interface CheckBoxProps {
  data: CheckBoxData[];
  focused: boolean;
  userColor;
  listeners;
}

export interface CheckBoxData {
  value: number;
  editable: boolean;
  error: string;
  label: string;
  required: boolean;
  name: string;
}
```

The error says: TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'CheckBoxData[]'.

Comment: Where you are adding data to `CheckBoxData[]`? it's seems to be empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that you need the `data: CheckBoxData` instead of `data: CheckBoxData[]`.

```
interface CheckBoxProps {
  data: CheckBoxData;
  focused: boolean;
  // type missing in following properties, temporarily fixed with any
  userColor: any;
  listeners: any;
}
```

I think the error message is pretty self explanatory that `data` has type `CheckBoxData[]` which makes `data` an array. So that destruction on that line is like writing `data.value`, an array doesn't have `value` property hence the error.